# Oracle sqlldr SQL Server new line character is getting loaded

Tags: sql-server, oracle, utf-8, character-encoding, sql-loader

I have a scenario where I am creating a file of a SQL Server table extract. The data contains European characters. Hence, I extract the data using the `bcp` utility, and I added `-C 65001` (converting text to UTF8 format).

The file is saved in Windows and moved to Unix.

Issue: the last column data of the file gets appended with new line character when loaded via SQL loader.

The charset is UTF8 in sql control file.

If I do unix to dos then the European characters also get changed to some garbage value (like boxes).

Could anyone please suggest why an invisible new line character is getting added in the column value. It should be recognized as line feed, not part of data.

Comment: Do you run sql-loader in Unix or Windows?

Comment: Is the character that's appended a new-line (10 decimal, 0A hex) or a carriage-return (13 decimal, 0D hex)? I'd expect the latter given the process you've described. You might try passing your file through the `dos2unix` filter program if it's available on your *nix box to convert Windows line endings (CR/LF) to *nix line endings (LF only) before giving the file to sqlldr.

Comment: The bcp utility doesn't write a BOM (Byte Order Mark, aka Preamble) when outputting UTF-8 files. If you're using `unix2dos` on *nix it won't see a UTF-8 BOM and so will assume the input file to be using whatever encoding `locale` outputs. This could be what's breaking your international characters. You should also be able to use `bcp.exe ... -r '0x0a'` to force linefeed row terminators to avoid the extra conversion process. Ref: [Specifying Terminators for Bulk Export](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server)

Comment: a quick hack to workaround it might be to have your last column defined as:  COL CHAR(x) "RTRIM(:COL,CHR(10))" in your sqlldr control file

Comment: I experienced the same issue. Is there any update on this ? @Suman